# Python parse with strptime - Month Day Hours:Minute:Seconds Year Timezone - Does not match format

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I'm having issues parsing "Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 GMT" with python's (datetime.datetime.strptime). I can't figure out what the issue is. At first I thought it was because the day was not zero padded, but according to the docs I found that is not the case.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z", "Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 GMT")
```

I've tried removing and adding whitespace to the format string. I've also tried going without the timezone specifier to no luck. The format I'm trying to parse comes from the ssl socket method `getpeercert`.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-a9f4aa24cc39> in <module>
----> 1 datetime.datetime.strptime("%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z", "Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 GMT")

/usr/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

/usr/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    357     if not found:
    358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z' does not match format 'Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 GMT'
```

What is the correct format string I should be using?

Comment: The error is insightful: `ValueError: time data '%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z' does not match format 'Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 `

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38147923/771848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```

The exact syntax should be as above. Changing the order of arguments would work.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 GMT","%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 3, 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to flip the args, ie:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("Mar  3 03:00:04 2019 GMT", "%b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")
```